# PHP include function for github pages

Tags: php, include, github-pages

I have a php website, from php I only used include, to make it easier to inline repeating elements (header / footer). I want to output a static html site that I can easily upload to github pages.

Is it difficult to implement or even possible?

**UPD**
Moved the answer in a separate comment.

Comment: Please create a [mre], show us some code, what you tried. Then we might can help you further.

Comment: Seems possible.

Comment: @codedge, Read my question carefully. To bring some code, I need to write my own plugin. If I could write my own plugin why would I ask a question here? In addition, I am not asking someone to write a whole plugin for me, there is probably a ready-made solution that I could not find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code copies everything from your directory with the php website (except for the includes folder and all files with the php extension) to another, arbitrary folder. And all files with the php extension are converted to html format and (except for the includes folder).

Ask what is it for? It's simple. You can conveniently work with all repeating elements (header.php, footer.php, etc.) by simply adding them to the includes folder, and in the pages themselves add via:

`<?php include 'includes/header.php'?>`

And then, when everything is ready, use a script to generate a static html/css/js site and upload it to the github pages for example. It is important to understand that github pages will not begin to understand php, this is all just to facilitate the development of a static html/css/js website.

!!!**The script must be in the same folder where you want, so that you end up with your static site**!!!

To run the script, go to the directory where the script is located in the console, write:

```
php copy.php
```

```
<?php
$source_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\source.com";

$destination_dir = "D:\openserver\domains\destination.com";

recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir);

function recursive_files_copy($source_dir, $destination_dir)
{
    // Open the source folder / directory
    $dir = opendir($source_dir);

    // Create a destination folder / directory if not exist
    @mkdir($destination_dir);

    // Loop through the files in source directory
    while ($file = readdir($dir))
    {
        // Skip . and ..
        if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file != 'includes') && (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'php'))
        {
            // Check if it's folder / directory or file
            if (is_dir($source_dir . '/' . $file))
            {
                // Recursively calling this function for sub directory
                recursive_files_copy($source_dir . '/' . $file, $destination_dir . '/' . $file);
            }
            else
            {
                // Copying the files
                copy($source_dir . '/' . $file, $destination_dir . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
        else if ((!is_dir($source_dir . '/' . $file)) && (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php'))
        {
            ob_start();
            include $source_dir . '/' . $file;
            $php_to_html = ob_get_clean();
            $fp = fopen($file, "w");
            fwrite($fp, $php_to_html);
            fclose($fp);
            rename(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME) , pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.html');
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
    // convertphp();
    
}
?>
```